# How to redirect to another page after 2 clicks?

Tags: javascript, click

I have a question about javascript. That is:

When I click first click **anywhere** in the website, this code will be executed

```
<a href="#" id="btn"></a>
```

When I click secondary click **anywhere** in the website, I will be redirect to another page.

How to do that ?

Thank you very much ! Sorry for my poor English and programmer !

Comment: What code? You posted a simple anchor that reloads the page and nothing else. No script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {

    counter = 0;
    document.body.onclick = function() {
        counter++;
        if(counter == 1) {
            document.getElementById('btn').click();
        }
        else if(counter == 2) {
            location.replace('http://www.google.com');
        }
    };

    document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function(e) {
        e.stopPropogation();
        alert('Link has been clicked!');
    };
}
</script>
```

Sorry, I am unable to create a fiddle for this, as jsfiddle prevents iframe page redirects out of its domain.

Comment: Hi, your code work great but I have problem. I want to hide button after first click. So I change `alert('Link has been clicked!');` by `$("#btn").hide();`. However, when I do first click, button was hided and redirect to google immediately. How to fix it ? Thank you very much !

Comment: Try document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
        $("#btn").hide();
    };

Comment: Hi Sajitha Rathnayake, I tried with your code but it doesn't work

Comment: Hi  Samuel Liew, when I do first click, it hided button and redirect to google immediately. Then, I change `counter == 3` and it works like a charm ! Thank you very much ! Sorry, I can't vote up for you because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Hi Samuel Liew, I have new problem. Your code work well when I access page directly. However, when I use your code in iframe, secondary click doesn't work. How to fix it ? Thanks